# Customizing bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: css, templates, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

We use the [bootstrap-Datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to show a popup date selection with date AND time.
The template shows two boxes, left one is the calendar view and works without any problem.
The right box shows this:

[image]

The arrows shown in the picture only show if you hover over them.
Is it possible to change this and at least show the arrows all the time?
Best would be to change it into something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please give us some code

Comment: What kind? Its a downloaded "addon" that is used, no custom code so far.
And it works fine, only the design is misleading the users, since you cant see the arrows, so you might be unsure how to change the time.

Comment: Can you send a link to the addon

Comment: Added the link to the js

Comment: I looked at the template and it seems that your error isn't caused by the template. I think this might be css related because it works error-free for me.

Comment: This seems more a problem with your custom css check out if you're not overwrtting anything, you can try it out using this fiddle and settin the following options https://jsfiddle.net/William_/20oywuno/  `debug: true,
  sideBySide: true,` using debug will not hide the picker